# Run a pyqt5 application directly on my Raspberry pi 3 without installation

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I have been trying to install PyQt5 on my raspberry pi 3 but everytime I try to install the library the pi freezes when it starts to compile or starts the  make line during installation.
I have now given up on trying to install the library as I have reinstalled the os many times. Is there a way I can somehow make it into an application and run it on the Pi directly without installing PyQt5.